# how to run php program that saved in opt/lampp/htdocs

Tags: 12.04, php, xampp

1. I installed Xampp in my linux os
2. I've also written a php program in gedit and saved it in /opt/lampp/htdocs

The problem is I don't know how to run the php file I saved in /opt/lampp/htdocs

Comment: This might help you.
Refer to this Video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CZoTgx2lgA

Answer (score 1):

If lampp is not already running start it from a Terminal `crtl + alt + t` type:

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Then open a browser and go to the url `localhost/yourFile.php`.
Replace `yourFile.php` with the name of your php file.

Or name the php file `index.php` and just enter `localhost` in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check if your lampp server is running or not.

If not, open your terminal by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

Type: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Something like this should appear:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-4...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Then, do as [Pabi](https://askubuntu.com/a/500577/230473) has suggested.

**localhost/yourfile.php** in your browser bar.

Answer (score 1):

firstly you will have to start the local host as mentioned

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

you will see the output on the termminal saying

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.1.9-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

you will have to check the permissions given to htdocs folder
to make life simpler try this

```
cd /opt/lampp
```

this will redirect you to the lampp folder , here change the permission of the document root , i.e permissions of htdocs

```
sudo chmod 777 htdocs
```

go into the folder

```
cd htdocs
```

now make your own document root file to store all your files

```
mkdir yourfoldername
```

now it is as simple as copying the files into this folder , now open your browser and type in

-> in your browser
localhost

you will see  -> localhost/dashboard/
remove the dashboard part and replace with

-> localhost/yourfoldername

and here click on the file you put inside the folder you had made in htdocs , and there you go . you can run the php file from here

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link in your `/var/www` folder pointing to `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.

```
mkdir /var/www/htdocs
ln -s /var/www/htdocs /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

From there just go to `localhost/htdocs`

Comment: This is not necessary as the default directory is `/opt/lmapp/htdocs` not `/var/www/htdocs`